# why adding \fbox around \includegraphics makes it lose the centering when using tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, fbox

in tex4ht, when doing

```
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
```

The image comes out centered. But when adding `fbox`, the images no longer is centered

```
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
```

I was not sure if this is by design or if it should remain centered. It does remain centered in pdf.  Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Phase plot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

gives

[image]

(btw, I never figured out how to make TL testimages show up as the true image on my system with tex4ht. They always show as PIC, but using actual image I have, same problem show up).

Now when adding `\fbox{....}` around the includegraphics here is the result

[image]

But in PDF, it remains centered even when adding `\fbox`

[image]

TL 2022 on Linux. Updated as of 12/29/2022

[Link to tracking](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?591)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a custom CSS in this case. `\centering` on it's own doesn't have and cannot have any effect on the resulting rendering of the document. You can try this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{figure > * {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; text-align:center;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This CSS instruction tells a browser that any child of the  `<figure>` element should be centered. For the `\fbox`, you also need the `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to auto, which will insert horizontal space around it in the way that it is centered.

This is the result (it is cropped, but it is really centered):

[image]